# improve speed of parsing fastq

Tags: performance, perl, parsing, fastq

@solved C# with the same code is twice as fast

i am parsing a phred33 fastq file in perl and it is taking a considerable amount of time (on the order of 15 minutes). The fastq file is about 3 gigs. 
Are there any reasonable ways to make this faster?

```
$file=shift;
open(FILE,$file);
open(FILEFA,">".$file.".fa");
open(FILEQA,">".$file.".qual");
while($line=<FILE>)
{
    chomp($line);
    if($line=~m/^@/)
    {


    $header=$line;
    $header =~ s/@/>/g;
    $seq=<FILE>;
    chomp($seq);
    $nothing=<FILE>;
    $nothing="";
    $fastq=<FILE>;

    print FILEFA $header."\n";
    print FILEFA $seq."\n";
    $seq="";
    print FILEQA $header."\n";

        @elm=split("",$fastq);
        $i=0;
        while(defined($elm[$i]))
        {
            $Q = ord($elm[$i]) - 33;
            if($Q!="-23")
            {
            print FILEQA $Q." ";
            }
            $i=$i+1;
        }
        print FILEQA "\n";
    }
}
print $file.".fa\n";
print $file.".qual\n";
```

Comment: I suppose if I were in your shoes, I'd probably fire up cachegrind...

Comment: Some quick googling: http://www.biostars.org/post/show/5005/ngs-huge-fastq-file-parsing-which-language-for-good-efficiency/ You might also try reading from `:raw` : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=837624 see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349604/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-read-10-gb-file-from-the-disk and perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052765/linux-perl-mmap-performance

Comment: I don't know much perl -- does `$nothing=<FILE>;` read the entire file in as an array?  Perhaps you're reading the entire file repeatedly?

Comment: @FrankFarmer thanks for the links i did read them but still dont know how to fix my code. $nothing=<FILE> reads a single line :)

Comment: `$nothing=<FILE>; $nothing = "";` contains *two* needless assignments. Just use `<FILE>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's next to no CPU being used here. it's IO bound, so it's mostly the time to read through 3GB. There are micro-optimisations (and other cleanups) that can be done.

First, always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

The main code is

```
my @elm = split(//, $fastq);
my $i=0;
while(defined($elm[$i])) {
    my $Q = ord($elm[$i]) - 33;
    if($Q!="-23") {
        print FILEQA $Q." ";
    }
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

The purpose of `if($Q!="-23")` is to check if the character is a newline, which you wouldn't have to do if you did `chomp($fastq);`. (What's with the quotes around `-23`?!)

```
chomp($fastq);
my @elm = split(//, $fastq);
my $i=0;
while(defined($elm[$i])) {
    my $Q = ord($elm[$i]) - 33;
    print FILEQA $Q." ";
    $i=$i+1;
}
print FILEQA "\n";
```

Using a `while` loop just complicates things. Use a for loop when you have a known number of iterations.

```
chomp($fastq);
for (split(//, $fastq)) {
    print FILEQA (ord($_)-33)." ";
}
print FILEQA "\n";
```

It might help a bit to turn that inside out.

```
chomp($fastq);
print FILEQA join(' ', map ord($_)-33, split //, $fastq), "\n";
```

On second thought, not inside out enough :)

```
$fastq =~ s/(.)/(ord($1)-33) . " "/eg;
print FILEQA $fastq;
```

But what it we precalculated the translations? Then we wouldn't have to call a sub (the `/e` code) repeatedly.

```
my %map = map { chr($_) => ($_-33)." " } 0x00..0xFF;

$fastq =~ s/(.)/$map{$1}/g;
print FILEQA $fastq;
```

---

After a bit more cleanup, we get:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %map = map { chr($_) => ($_-33)." " } 0x00..0xFF;

my $file = shift;

my $fa_file   = "$file.fa";
my $qual_file = "$file.qual";

open(my $FILE,   '<', $file     ) or die $!;
open(my $FILEFA, '>', $fa_file  ) or die $!;
open(my $FILEQA, '>', $qual_file) or die $!;

while (my $header = <$FILE>) {
    next if $header !~ /^@/;

    my $seq = <$FILE>;
    <$FILE>;
    my $fastq = <$FILE>;

    $header =~ s/@/>/g;
    $fastq =~ s/(.)/$map{$1}/g;

    print $FILEFA $header;
    print $FILEFA $seq;

    print $FILEQA $header;
    print $FILEQA $fastq;
}

print "$fa_file\n";
print "$qual_file\n";
```

Comment: @caseyr547, It probably won't make a major difference, like I explained.

Comment: Maybe it you read bigger blocks of data at at time (say 64KB) using `sysread`, then extract the lines from that (i.e. do your own buffering with a larger buffer). Perl 5.14 uses 8K readers (and made it configurable at build-time) whereas older Perl used 4K readers, so Perl 5.14 would actually help.

Comment: For the curious: that PerlIO buffer configure flag is [`PERLIOBUF_DEFAULT_BUFSIZ`](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#Configuration-and-Compilation)

Comment: @ikegami i guess on this perl is just slow...C# is twice as fast